# Click element by element in the list

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

How can I click element by element in the list where the locator looks like this:

```
id=${NameFirst.replace(" ", ""}_${NameLast.replace(" ", "")}

    *Keywords*
    | Get all first and last names
    | | ${Name} | Query Master Database
    | | ... | 
    | | [Return] | ${Name[0][0]} | ${Name[0][1]}

    *Test Case*
    | Click element by element
    | | :FOR | ${NameElement} | IN | @{NameElementList}
    | | ${NameFirst} | ${NameLast}= | Get all first and last names
    | | set suite variable | ${NameFirst}
    | | set suite variable | ${NameLast}
    | | Click Element | id=${NameFirst.replace(" ", ""}_${NameLast.replace(" ", "")}
```

When I run test case it clicks the first element only

```
INFO ${Name} = [['AAA', 'BBB'], ['CCC', 'DDD']]
INFO    ${NameFirst} = AAA
INFO    ${NameLast} = BBB
```

Comment: You are not using `${NameElement}` anywhere in the FOR loop which makes the loop pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears that your loop isn't formatted correctly. The body of the loop needs an extra level of indentation. The following example illustrates:

```
*Test Case*
| Click element by element
| | :FOR | ${NameElement} | IN | @{NameElementList}
| | | ${NameFirst} | ${NameLast}= | Get all first and last names
| | | set suite variable | ${NameFirst}
| | | set suite variable | ${NameLast}
| | | Click Element | id=${NameFirst.replace(" ", ""}_${NameLast.replace(" ", "")}
```

Here the lines belonging to forloop needs be be spaced out leaving one cell. PFA[image: For loop example]